# Feature with multiple attributes/properties

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I want to build a machine learning model where each feature has further multiple attributes.

Apologies for the lame example, but this will convey my doubt:

Predict the animal on the basis of its fingers(let's say 5 fingers of one paw of that animal). In this case, 5 fingers are the features and each finger has its length, width, and nail-length as attributes.

The following table describes one example. Let's say this example corresponds to lion.

|  | Length | Breadth | Nail-length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finger-1 | 3 cm | 2 cm | 1.5 cm |
| Finger-2 | 4 cm | 3 cm | 2 cm |
| Finger-3 | 3.5 cm | 1.5 cm | 2.5 cm |
| Finger-4 | xx cm | xx cm | xx cm |
| Finger-5 | xx cm | xx cm | xx cm |

Now, these 5-fingers are one set of information. How can I convert this to a feature without losing any information? I cannot split this information because for each finger the length, breadth, and nail-length are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flattening the information is most common and intuitive choice, before trying something else. So, the new features will look like

Finger-1-Length, Finger-1-Breadth, Finger-1-Nail-length, Finger-2-Length, Finger-2-Breadth, Finger-2-Nail-length ... and so on.

This gives you a 15 dimensional feature space.

Comment: Wouldn't then some vital information would be lost? Some other animal having the same data but in different combinations will be forced to be considered as same.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's lost in this representation.

Comment: I mean how will the model know that `finger-1-length`, `finger-1-breadth` and `finger-1-nail-length` are related?

Comment: Well, similarly, finger 1 and finger 2 can be related as well. There may always be dependency between the features, and some machine learning methods already addresses them if they're needed or useful (e.g. non-naive bayesian methods).

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  Is there a way to tell the model that `finger-1-length`, `finger-1-breadth`, and `finger-1-nail-length` belong to one group? Suppose I add another column `finger-type` like `thumb`, `forefinger` etc. This data will be lost after flatenning.

Comment: I don't think you need to do this. What kind of machine learning model are you going to use? Is it something very particular that requires such an information to be inputted explicitly? The simplest similarity to your problem is the Iris dataset where there are two kinds of leaves (petal and sepal) and their lengths and widths. I've never seen an example trying to group petal length and width; sepal length and width. If the features have importance and the model is able, it'll pick what's useful.

Comment: I am not able to convey my problem properly. I have categorical attributes related to the features and I want the model explicitly to know about those attributes.

Comment: what kind of model are you going to use?

Comment: Thanks, gunes. I have done more research and found that LSTM is a better solution, as my data is sequencial.